# Where can I learn this Python bracket operator?

Tags: python, flask

I was looking at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/views/) those days and in their user guide I found a Python snippet as below

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    cur = g.db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

Here

```
entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

creates a list of entries from the database. It is my first time to know to generate a list with a loop inside the bracket.

Can anyone help me point out where I can find the official intro. for such syntax ? is it only limited to list but not tuple nor anything else?

Many Thanks.
S.

Comment: list comprehension... there are lots of questions about that

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the answers to this question are rather *interesting* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is called **list comprehension**

I think this should be the official docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 3):

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

Its called a List Comprehension, here is a link to the python documentation.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

And some more examples:

http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a list comprehension.

This would be a nice start: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

You can start here:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions